# Where does the extra mass of a $W$ boson come from in particle decay?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, bosons, electroweak

I’ve seen everywhere explaining that it can exist because of time/energy uncertainty. I get this. I understand that’s WHY it exists but I’ve still never gotten WHERE the extra mass comes from. Is the mass not actually measured/detected? Nobody seems to be able to explain how we get from mass energy value X to a higher mass energy value Y. Only that we CAN because of uncertainty. I’m probably slightly misinterpreting some concepts but it is not satisfactory AT ALL to just say well it has a higher mass because of uncertainty...

Comment: Are you asking about the virtual W particles in, for example, beta decay? If so the virtual particle doesn't actually exist. It is just a way of approximating the interaction between the quantum fields. Or are you asking about creating real W particles in a high energy collision? In that case the kinetic energy is converted to the mass of the real W particle.

Comment: In particle decay, there is a well known “violation of conservation” due to the extra mass of the virtual particle, that is t really a violation because of time-energy uncertainty. I understand that the virtual W boson is a virtual particle but it is still calculated to have approximately 81 GeV. I also understand that while particles are virtual it’s not as if they don’t actually exist, the virtual W boson has a real effect in particle decay and mediates a real force, I guess it’s just that a clear picture of what’s actually happening hasn’t been painted in terms that accounts for everything

Comment: I think you need to make your question much more specific.  Draw or describe the Feynman diagram that you are trying to understand.  Explain at exactly which point in the diagram you believe that a conservation law has been violated and why (i.e., which quantities you are already taking into account).  The very brief answer is that energy is *always* conserved, and if you think that there is missing energy, it's because you have skipped counting the energy somewhere.  But I can't make this more specific without a more specific scenario to work with.

Comment: Have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOiABZM7wTU)

Comment: [Matt Strassler's explanation of "virtual particles"](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/virtual-particles-what-are-they/) might be at a good level to address this question.  In short, "virtual particles" are not particles: they are non-particle-like excitations of quantum fields, which (among other features) do not have a well-defined mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no extra mass  going to virtual particles because they are not on mass shell. Read on.

In [this link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html)  a virtual photon is defined,second page, needed in calculating the crossection of electron electron scattering.(for low energies)

[image: ee]

The internal virtual lines are just a mnemonic in the integral that will give measurable quantities, a mnemonic with the particle name, because it carries the quantum numbers of a photon, BUT the four vector ( energy momentum one) that describes it within the integral has a continuously varying mass, it is *not on mass shell.*

In addition within the integral, [the mathematical propagator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Position_space) that describes the line has the mass of the named particle,

[image: feynman propag]

and here, further down in the first link, is the weak interaction mediated by W

[image: beta]

In the case of the W, which has an enormous mass compared with the neutron
the four vectors are way off mass shell within the energy constraints of the interaction.

If you study  further into this, $e^+e^-$ scattering for example, one can see scanning from low to high energies [the width of what are virtual particles](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/hadronic-xsections/rpp2018-sigma_R_ee.pdf) by the increase and decrease in the cross section. (in this linked plot one could use the Heisenberg uncertainty for energy time, to estimate the lifetime, as long as measurement errors have been taken into account)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess what’s really confusing me now is whether the virtual W boson actually exists for any amount of time in the middle of the decay process. Is there an actual W boson or is it really just “virtual”? Where does the W boson actually come from? Is it the same as when electrons excite the EM field to produce a virtual photon? Is the W bosons only purpose in nature to mediate beta decay? If so then how did we recreate the particle in particle accelerators? What a confusing particle lol

Comment: Quantum mechanics and particle physics using it to model measurements have a different definition of "exist" than classical mechanics.What "exist"are the four vectors measured in experiments. Virtual particles exist only  in the mathematics, as place holders for the quantum numbers and energy momentum and angular momentum with the integration. The "existing" particles are a validation of the mathematical models.The W exists when the energy is high enough   in the event to allow its four vector to become real, by adding up to the real particles (four vector on mass shell) that it decays into.

Comment: see  http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/~adye/4j.html  . It is  a complicated mathematical model of nature, but is continually validated in its predictions.. The W observed existed for the amount of time given by the width of the accumulation of such events. If we had good enough detectors we would see it the way we saw the muon decaying in the bubble  chambers  look at "would you  like to see a muon"https://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCwebsite/index.htm