# When a Z boson decays into a particle/antiparticle pair, do those particles instantly annihilate each other?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, virtual-particles, weak-interaction, bosons

If you look at a Feynman diagram of neutrino-electron scattering, there is the mediation of force by means of a virtual Z boson, and the product of this interaction is just the neutrino and electron you started with, however the Z boson decays into a net 0 charge particle/antiparticle pair right? I’m assuming it instantly annihilates because you aren’t left with anything extra...

Comment: Check out Matt Strassler's post about why you shouldn't take the idea of virtual particles too literally. https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/virtual-particles-what-are-they/

Comment: Ah so it is only the lab recreated Z boson that decays? I figured it was the case

Comment: @gabe see there we go. Why is it so hard for scientists do describe it in that way, where it actually makes sense lol. Thank you

Comment: The $Z$ isn’t decaying in neutrino-electron scattering. It is simply being exchanged between the neutrino and the electron. On the other hand, a collision between a neutrino and an anti-neutrino, or between an electron and a positron, can produce a $Z$ which then decays to an electron and a positron, or a neutrino and an anti-neutrino.

Comment: see my answer to a related question here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/494353/where-does-the-extra-mass-of-a-w-boson-come-from-in-particle-decay/494438#494438

Comment: Can someone post their reply in the answer section so I can mark this as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [Z decay](https://cms.cern/news/first-z-bosons-detected-cms-heavy-ion-collisions) to e+e-  in lead lead collisions in CMS:

[image: Ze+e-]

The Z is "virtual" as we do not have fine grain enough detectors to see the vertex of e+e- as different in space  than the event vertex, and thus know the distance the Z travelled. We know it is a Z because the mass of the summed fourvectors of the e+ e- gives the mass of the Z.

So you see that the two particles it decays to go different ways and never meet to annihilate. The reason is basic, in *their center of  mass* there has to be energy and momentum conservation. Energy conservation devides the energy from the mass of the Z  energy to the two leptons, part of the energy will become kinetic as the electrons have a very low mass, momentum conservation forces the two electrons in equal and opposite directions, in the center of mass system. They never meet to annihilate.